# I can mount a samba share from windows and see what it holds but cannot create files or directories

Tags: centos, samba, windows-10, samba4, xfs

[Newbie warning! this is my first time setting up Samba.  I'm almost there but...]

Server is running Centos 8, Samba V4.10.4
Shared filesystem is xfs, I have enabled extended attributes and tested that so it is working.
I have also tested samba's ability to save dos attributes but I think the problem is probably that something is misconfigured in the ACL's or extended attributes.

I want to use this server to backup a windows 10 pro PC.

Situation is that I can browse the server and mount its shares but I cannot create files or directories from the client side. I created a directory on the share locally that I can see from the client.

If I try to create a new folder from windows I get "Destination folder access denied."
On the server /var/logs/log.smbd this shows up as

```
[2020/06/04 17:39:06.739107,  2] ../../source3/smbd/open.c:4057(open_directory)
  open_directory: unable to create New folder. Error was NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2020/06/04 17:39:13.790033,  2] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:837(remove_child_pid)
  Could not find child 28630 -- ignoring
[2020/06/04 17:39:15.092117,  2] ../../lib/util/tevent_debug.c:66(samba_tevent_debug)
  samba_tevent: EPOLL_CTL_DEL EBADF for fde[0x556b012716b0] mpx_fde[(nil)] fd[15] - disabling
```

I have defined a [homes] share but it doesn't show up when I browse the server.  Don't care about that.
I do care about windows ACL's.

I have defined two samba accounts and associated Linux accounts.  "hank" is the same userid that I have on the windows client and it is mapped to my linux account using smbusers.  "hankwin" is not mapped and does not have a login shell on linux.  I can use either of these to mount their corresponding shares to the windows machine.

When I look at the folder properties from windows under security it shows that nobody has any permissions to do anything on the share or on the sub-folder.

icacls on the client gives  the following report for the share [hankwin] mounted at y: and the subfolder y:\stuff

```
icacls y:
y: S-1-5-21-1897013661-3875350279-343821458-1021:(F)
   S-1-22-2-1003:(RX)
   Everyone:(RX)
   CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
   CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
   Everyone:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
>icacls y:\stuff
y:\stuff S-1-5-21-1897013661-3875350279-343821458-1021:(F)
         S-1-22-2-1003:(RX)
         Everyone:(RX)
         CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
         CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
         Everyone:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Here are the Linux file permissions

```
drwxrws---. 3 hankwin winshare 35 Jun  4 16:52 hankwin
drwxrws---. 2 root    winshare  6 Jun  4 16:29 hank
ls -l *
hank:
total 0

hankwin:
total 0
drwxr-sr-x. 2 hankwin winshare 6 Jun  4 16:52 stuff
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 hankwin winshare 0 Jun  4 12:02 test.txt
```

The file test.txt is invisible from the client.

Here's the smb.conf file

```
[global]
        path = /srv/smb
        writeable = yes
        printing = cups
        security = user
        netbios name = konishiki
        load printers = yes
        sync always = yes
        create mode = 777
        os level = 20
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY
        cups options = raw
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        printcap name = cups
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        directory mode = 777
        encrypt passwords = yes
        log level = 2
        unix password sync = yes
        vfs objects = acl_xattr
        map acl inherit = yes
        wins support = yes
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        admin users = hank, hankwin hcohe



[homes]
        inherit acls = Yes
        browseable = no
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        writable = yes
        path = /home
        comment = Home Directories

[hankwin]
        path = /srv/smb/hankwin/
        read only = no
        store dos attributes = yes

[hank]
        path = /srv/smb/hank
        read only = no
        store dos attributes = yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
```

Thanks to anyone with the perseverance to wade through all this.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Hank Cohen

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
The problem was that selinux was not giving samba the necessary permissions to export shares.  This fixed it.

```
 setsebool -P -V samba_export_all_rw=on samba_export_all_rw=on
```

This solution may be specific to Centos or RHEL 8.  Also if you want to allow users to mount home directories there's another bool for that.